# How to solve Explicity Deny when granting permissino to a ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to grant access to a Elastice Container Repository to a group of users and I use the following managed policies:

- AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
                "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:PutImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
                "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But the users get the following error:

[image]

> There was an error fetching the repositories: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:user/USERA is not authorized to perform: ecr:DescribeRepositories on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:XXXX:repository/* with an explicit deny

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have another policy attached that denies the `ecr:DescribeRepositories` permission. Refer to [the policy evaluation flowchart in the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html) to see how this works. You should look at the complete permission set associated with the user and look for the policy that has the explicit deny.

Comment: Thank you Ben Whaley, I had a 2FA requirement policy

Comment: Cool! If this answer helped you, please accept it! :)